# Trackpad multitouch gestures on 13.04

Tags: 13.04, acer, multi-touch

I have Ubuntu 13.04 on an Acer Aspire 5750 that has a trackpad. I'd like to use 3 or 4 finger multitouch gestures to perform certain actions.

I can use 2 fingers to scroll, but I would like to, for example, use 3 fingers to change open windows - kind of like an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - and other multitouch gestures. I have no clue if my trackpad is capable of this kind of stuff. If it is, does Ubuntu 13.04 support it, and how can I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

`touchegg` used to do what you wanted. Somehow ubuntu developers removed `utouch` the key package on which `touchegg` depends to catch gestures ... Now I am like you stuck at what ubuntu developers do to us by droppping such important packages and removing important features from ubunutu while upgrading!!! I regret leaving oneiric updating to raring :(

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Synaptik touchpad manager from Ubuntu Software Center. It has the option for advanced multi-touch gestures which would enable if your system supports them....and many more options.

Comment: i want a program that can kind of set custom macros.... like if i scroll left or right with 3 fingers it will change windows or workspaces.....

Comment: did you manage to find anything?